# A linear transformation that fixes a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am struggling with the problem below:

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, and $L: V \longrightarrow V$ a linear transformation over $F$. Define a sequence of subspaces $V_0, V_1, V_2, ...$ of $V$ inductively by $V_0 = V$, and $V_{n+1} = L(V_n)$ for $n \geq 1$. Prove that there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $V_{N + 1} = V_N$.

I observed that $V_0 = V$, $V_1 = L(V)$, $V_2 = L^2(V)$, ... That is, $V_K = L^K(V)$. Thus, to show $V_{N + 1} = V_N$, we need to show that $L^{N+1}(V) = L^N(V)$, which occurs if and only if $L^N(V) \cdot (L(V) -1) = 0$, which is true if and only if $L(V)$ is the identity operator or $L$ is nilpotent.

Thus, I've reduced the question down to proving that $L$ is either the identity transformation or nilpotent. How can I proceed with the proof? I'm not sure where to go from here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last claim is false. $L^N(V) \cdot (L(V) - 1) = 0$ does not imply that $L^N = 0$ or $L = 1$. The composition of nonzero linear transformations may be zero. Note that the statement you are trying to prove is stated for an arbitrary linear transformation $L \colon V \to V$, not just nilpotent ones or the identity.

Instead, observe that
$$V \supseteq L(V) \supseteq L^2(V) \supseteq \cdots,$$
thus
$$\dim_F(V) \geq \dim_F(L(V)) \geq \dim_F(L^2(V)) \geq \cdots.$$
Can you see why there must exist $N$ such that $\dim_F(L^{N + 1}(V)) = \dim_F(L^N(V))$, which implies $L^{N + 1}(V) = L^N(V)$?

Comment: Hi Ethan. Thank you for pointing out my mistake about the composition of two nonzero linear transformations. I believe I see why this works. In that dimension sequence you have, suppose the dimension never stabilizes. Then, since these dimensions are always greater than or equal zero, this implies the dimension of some subspace is zero. But then, that implies the linear transformation L is nilpotent, and the claim follows. Is this the right thinking?

Comment: @testguy807 No. Nilpotent transformations are not relevant here. The dimensions stabilize because they are nonnegative integers which decrease, i.e., it cannot be that $\dim_F(L^n(V)) > \dim_F(L^{n + 1}(V))$ for all $n$ because then there would have to be some $n$ such that $\dim_F(L^n(V)) < 0$, which is clearly impossible. There is no reason why the dimension has to reach $0$ however. For example, if $L$ is invertible, all of the dimensions are equal to $\dim_F(V)$.